# If $T : V \to V$, $\operatorname{nullity}(T) = 0$, is $T$ onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Use the given information to determine whether the linear operator is
> one-to-one, onto, both, or neither.

Given: $T : V \to V$ is linear and $\operatorname{null}(T)=0$

I know it is one to one because the $\operatorname{null}(T)=0$, but I'm not sure if it is onto or not.

According my text book;

Theorem 8.1.3:

(a) The kernel of $T$ is a subspace of $V$.

(b)The range of $T$ is a subspace of $W$.

In this Theorem it shows that $b$ ($b = T(V)$) is a subspace of $V$.

Is this subspace - $T(V)$ - equal to $V$ in this given these conditions? As we know, a subspace of $V$ can be itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that the range of $T$ is a vector subspace of $V$, but it may not always be all of $V$.

Specifically, if $T:V\to V$ is linear, $V$ is finite dimensional, and $\dim\ker T = 0$, then $T$ is surjective (in fact, $T$ is an isomorphism). To prove this, pick a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ for $V$ and show that $\{Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n\}\subseteq\text{im}\,T$ is a basis for $V$.
Conclude that

> $\dim\text{im}\,T=\dim V$ so $\text{im}\,T=V$.

In the case that $V$ is infinite dimensional, this may not be true.

Hint: Set $V$ to be

> $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the set of all polynomials with real coefficients in the variable $x$

and define $T:V\to V$ by

> $T(p) = xp$.